# Select before aggregate with Pandas, python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty new to Pandas in python and i need help to see if I'm doing it right. Basically i have an excel file containing data and I'm using pandas to play with the data. The question mentions that i can select four ports before aggregating in terms of Year and Ports. So i tried something like this.

```
filterport = portTraffic.Port.isin(['Adelaide','Brisbane','Sydney','Melbourne'])          
            
new = portTraffic[filterport]
year_port = new.groupby(['Year','Port'])
```

I obtain an output (if i print the head) only showing me the data of the four ports i filtered but I wonder if I'm doing it correctly?

## note, portTraffic is the excel file

Comment: So you're getting the correct results but wondering if you're doing it correctly? If you don't perform an aggregation operation on a `GroupBy` then `.head()` will just look like the regular dataframe.

Comment: @CorryMadden spot on! I was curious on why the head() looked like the regular dataframe. So does this mean the groupby(['Year','Port')] isn't aggregating?

Comment: No, it's just preparing for an aggregation. The actual aggregation is something like `sum()` or `count()`.  Look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id32)

Comment: Can you past a sample of your inputs and expected outputs in this question.